# Application of Multinomial Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-theorem

I just read in Cengage's Algebra that in order to find the number of some constraint bounded solutions of an equation (say, non negative integral), it would be the same as the coefficient of $x^n$ in expansion of $(x^1 + x^2 + ... x^\text{(max value attainable by variable)})^\text{(no. of variables)}$. How come ? What is the logic behind the coefficient of $x^n$ and no. of solutions being same ?

Comment: Try some small cases, like $3$ variables, maximum value $2$.

Comment: I think that instead of $$(x^\text{least value attainable by variable} + x^2 + ... x^\text{(max value attainable by variable)})^\text{(no. of variables)}$$, and in the case that you mention, i.e. non-negative integral solution, then you gotta include $0$, also to get the generating function as $(x^0+x^1 + x^2 + ... x^\text{(max value attainable by variable)})^\text{(no. of variables)}$

Comment: Yes I am sorry I wrote the expression for positive solutions while mentioning non-negative.... But please explain why this happens..... I still don't get it.